# docker-compose redis connection issue

Tags: node.js, mongodb, docker, redis, docker-compose

I have been trying to dockerize an api . But redis crashes. Nodejs and mongodb work.

Docker-compose.yaml file

```
version: '3'
services:

  mongo:
    container_name: mongo
    image: mongo
    networks:
      - webnet
    ports:
      - '27017:27017'
  redis: 
    image: redis
    container_name: redis
    command: ["redis-server","--bind","redis","--port","6379"]
    ports:
      - '6379:6379'
    hostname: redis

  app:
    container_name: password-manager-docker
    restart: always
    build: .
    networks:
      - webnet
    ports:
      - '80:5000'
    links: 
      - mongo
      - redis
    environment: 
      MONGODB_URI: ${MONGODB_URI}
      clientID: ${clientID}
      clientSecret : ${clientSecret}
      PORT: ${PORT}
      NODE_ENV : ${NODE_ENV}
      JWT_SECRET_KEY: ${JWT_SECRET_KEY}
      JWT_EXPIRE: ${JWT_EXPIRE}
      REFRESH_TOKEN: ${REFRESH_TOKEN}
      JWT_REFRESH_SECRET_KEY: ${JWT_REFRESH_SECRET_KEY}
      JWT_REFRESH_EXPIRE: ${JWT_REFRESH_EXPIRE}
      JWT_COOKIE: ${JWT_COOKIE}
       
networks:
  webnet:
```

Docker file

```
FROM node:latest

WORKDIR /usr/src/app

COPY package*.json ./

RUN npm install 

COPY . .

EXPOSE 5000

CMD ["npm","start"]
```

The error is Redis connection to 127.0.0.1:6379 failed - connect ECONNREFUSED 127.0.0.1:6379.
How can I fix this ?

Comment: From the application try to connect to redis:6379 instead of 127.0.0.1

Comment: I've tried. But the same error.Redis connection to 6379 failed

Comment: Maybe other service is occupying that port? What is the result of ‘docker ps’?

Comment: There are 3 container and ports 
0.0.0.0:80->5000/tcp 
,0.0.0.0:6379->6379/tcp (redis container)
,0.0.0.0:27017->27017/tcp

Comment: You are overriding the default CMD for redis with `command`. It should work out-of-the-box if you don't mess with the command that is used for starting the container.

Comment: @OğulcanKarayel could you please change redis command to ‘ command: ["redis-server","--bind","0.0.0.0","--port","6379"]’ and verify if does it help

Comment: I fixed this thanks. Now, how can I deploy this app to heroku ? Do you know any tutorial or something else to help me

Comment: @OğulcanKarayel please follow https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/local-development-with-docker-compose

Answer (score 0):

by default all containers in a compose file will join a default network where they can communicate with each other, but if you specify a network then you have to specify it for all.  So you can either remove the network declaration from the app and mongo services or specify it on the redis service.

Comment: Where are you specifying the redis connection time your app?

Comment: I'm not specifying connection time.

Comment: It worked after added the host property to the redis client configuration. But how can I access the api. localhost:80 and localhost:5000 not working

Comment: I assume when you say api you are referring to your app service, if so then it should be localhost:80. Are you getting a 404 or any other error?

Comment: The error is this site is not available.But when I run docker-machine ip and use this ip it works. Ex, ip is 192.168.10.10. I write the url 192.168.10.10:80,then it works. Is it ok for deployment ? If not,how can I run localhost:80

Comment: Is there a reason you are using docker machine(https://github.com/docker/machine/issues/4537)?  Do you have multiple docker machines on your host?